# Butterknife bind in anonymous listener class

Tags: android, butterknife

I want to show a custom dialog when a FloatingActionButton is clicked. Since it is a custom dialog, thus it needs a layout file (`dialog_layout.xml` in this case), the layout file contains several components, and I want butterknife to bind these components and interpret it within the onClick listener before the dialog is shown.

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @BindView(R.id.lblTextView)
    TextView lblTextView;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(), view);

        //I need to do something with lblTextView here but it returns NullPointerException

        //create dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(view)
        //...
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

What I have also tried:

- `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)`
- `ButterKnife.bind(view, view)`
- `ButterKnife.bind(view)`

Is there anyhing I have missed? Am I doing it wrong? The snippet above is inside a `Fragment`.

Comment: Check this doc http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: @Newbie have answered below, please review that.

Comment: Review the updated answer, problem get solved now. I've verified myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below, have verified myself. Solves your issue.

**Step1:** Create an inner class

```
public class DialogView {
    @BindView(R.id.lblTextView)
    TextView lblTextView;

    public DialogView(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        //do whatever want with lblTextView
        //create dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

**Step2:** Modify your button clicklistener call like below

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        new DialogView(view);
     }
}
```

Comment: Still return null

Comment: Review the updated answer, problem get solved now. I've verified myself.